# Convert time in seconds to 24-Hour clock and AM/PM clock

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

Maybe it is a basic problem but it confused me. How can we formulate a translation of given seconds to 24 hour clock or am/pm clock.

For example; 77400 seconds is $21:30:0$ in 24 hour clock and $9:30:0$ $PM$ in am/pm clock.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found something.

For 24-hour clock :

$H = T / 3600$

$M = (T \mod 3600) / 60 $

$S = (T \mod 3600) \mod 60$

24-hour clock;

> H : M :S

For AM/PM clock:

There is only one difference. If $H > 12$,

AM/PM clock;

> (H-12) : M : S PM

Else,

> H : M : S AM

Comment: ... except that in countries that use a 12-hour clock, $H=0$ is written "12" instead, so the hours go 12:xx AM, 1:xx AM, 2:xx AM, ... 11:xx AM, 12:xx PM, 1:xx PM, 2:xx PM ... and writing down 00:00:00 and 12:00:00 is sometimes deliberately avoided because it's not clear whether that should be AM or PM.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I am not sure about that but wiki says that in Japan it should be 0:00 AM and in USA 12:00 AM. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/12-hour_clock

Answer (score 1):

For 24 hour clock (next variant is straightforward, try to think about it):

Let $T$ for number of seconds you get as an input.

You can count number of hours as:
$$H := \lfloor\ T\ /\ 3600\ \rfloor.$$

Same goes for minutes and for seconds, but you need to substract second which count to full hours.

So for minutes, you need to take:

$$M := \lfloor\ (T \mod 3600)\ / \ 60\ \rfloor.$$

So in the end you get final time as

$$H : M : (T - H \cdot 3600 - M \cdot 60).$$